# Find and Replace script for textWrangler

Tags: scripting, textwrangler, macos-sierra

I'm trying to make a script that will find and replace some xml structure.

I've made it all flat, no spaces, no return.

So far I've made :

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
    replace text "<key>amenity</key><string>drinking_water</string>" using text "<key>ico</key>
<string>NPpotableGPS30</string>"
end tell
```

The script editor says :

```
  Error in TextWrangler : text "<key>amenity</key><string>drinking_water</string>" don't have the message « replace ».
```

This is my first script so I'm probably doing something wrong, but what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key "`text`" seems to be misplaced. The following appears to correctly work (the sequence from `searching` onwards being optional for defining the document to process, according to actual working situation):

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
 replace "<key>amenity</key><string>drinking_water</string>" using "<key>ico</key><string>NPpotableGPS30</string>" searching in text 1 of text document "..." options {search mode:grep, starting at top:true}
end tell
```